# Reboot Android device and apply update.zip automatically

Tags: android

Is it possible to reboot Android and have the "apply update.zip" menu item invoked automatically? I think it is possible to call PowerManager.reboot with the parameter "recovery". Are there more options that I can pass to the reboot() method or is there some other way to do this?

Comment: If you are asking about your own custom firmware, StackOverflow has not traditionally been a good resource for that sort of question. If you are asking about this from the standpoint of an SDK application, then the answer is "no, you cannot do this".

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm asking about my own custom firmware. Is there a dedicated stack exchange site for Android development? I do see http://android.stackexchange.com but that's for users, right? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of a Stack-y site dedicated to firmware stuff. Most of that work seems to be on xda-developers and sites of that ilk.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Oh, OK. I'll head there. Thanks.